# linux writing string value to hex, difference between x86 and i368?

Tags: c++, linux, string, serial-port, hex

relating to my post [linux writing string value as hex to serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654024/linux-writing-string-value-as-hex-to-serial) (which was solved on a x86 System)
I have a problem on an i368 system.
The code works on an intel atom ubuntu system.
But on an intel xeon with ubuntu this doesnt work anymore.

Could that be a problem o little/big endian?

I used the code of the mentioned post from Erik.

I am using this method to convert

```
int convert(std::string str, unsigned char*& charArr)
{


// count the number of character pairs (i.e. bytes) in the string
// and dynamically allocate an array of the required size
const int numBytes = str.size() / 2;
charArr = new unsigned char[numBytes];

for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; ++i)
{
  // grab two characters from the string...
  std::string twoChars = str.substr(2 * i, 2);

  // ...and convert them to an integer using a stringstream
  int byte;
  std::stringstream ss(twoChars);
  ss >> std::hex >> byte;

  // store the result in our char array
  charArr[i] = byte;
}
}
```

Calling the method by

```
const std::string str ="8C000002008E";
unsigned char* toSend;
convert(str, toSend);
```

And writing to the serial Port with:

```
int kWrite = write(mFd, toSend , sizeof(toSend));
```

The serial device react on the atom system, but not on the xeon.

The response i get says: undefined format or checksum error

Comment: Define *doesnt work anymore*

Comment: And define "this code". It is always better to post everything in the question, rather than give external links.

Comment: No, Atom and Xeon are both little-endian processors, so byte order has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Most likely he compiled with options allowing the use of some of the newer features, and his Xeon system is older, and doesn't have them.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Ok thanks good to know. One thing when i am defining the char array "manualy" like    unsigned char[6] = {0x8C,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x8E};  and then send it, it works

Comment: @JamesKanze: this is an newer xeon cpu, or which feature you mentioned?

Comment: @Livingstone: I have a feeling you are filling your byte array backwards when you parse the string the way you are doing it right now. You should probably start at the end and work toward the beginning.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman already tried this, but did not help. Always getting parse error response from serial device

Comment: @Livingstone If I had a concrete answer, I would have posted it as an answer:-).  It's just speculation on my part, or perhaps an indication of a direction you might want to look into.  I do know that some C++ compilers use more advanced instructions (like the SSE registers) by default, and that these are not present on older processors; there could easily be other issues as well.

Comment: If it works, when you define it manually, you should be able to look at what is generated instead and at which statement exactly this goes wrong.

Comment: The posted code doesn't work anywhere (not to mention that it leaks memory).  You write `sizeof(toSend)` bytes, but `toSend` is a pointer.  Use `std::vector<unsigned char> toSend` instead of the pointer, and write `&toSend[0], toSend.size()`.  And forget about the dynamic allocation.

Comment: For the sake of debugging. On Xeon what do you see if you did a hex-dump of the toSend buffer before you send it ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, got the head full of work. Ill debug and post the result as soon as possible